# Generating a printable table (.pdf) from customized input

Tags: php, forms

I would like to create some way of generating a ballot on my website. A person can enter a custom number of names, and it will generate a ballot [like this](http://i.imgur.com/CT1ra.png). The final ballot would need to be an easily printable 8.5x11 .pdf.

I have only a basic knowledge of PHP, and I'm just looking for a general guide of what I would need to do--I don't need a full code written for me. Is this something that can be done somewhat simply?

Comment: Check out [link](http://www.fpdf.org/), it is a PHP library for creating PDF documents

Comment: I can't testify to it's quality but there is this - https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: I think I'm going to go with dompdf. I installed it and it looks like it's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), and it worked incredibly well.

Answer (score 1):

FPDF is very useful, I would highly recommend it. And it's free.

http://www.fpdf.org/